# Do commits within a stored procedure called by ODP.NET get applied if the transaction is rolled back?

Tags: transactions, odp.net

Suppose my stored procedure `do_something_dangerous` ends with `COMMIT;`

Further suppose my application uses `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` to call this stored procedure:

```
OracleTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
...
doSomethingDangerousCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
transaction.Rollback();
```

Will the commit in `do_something_dangerous` be applied or not? Is this behavior configurable?

Answer (score 0):

This should be answered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/24506990/428805

> Oracle doesn't support nested transactions. If a transaction commits,
>   it commits. That's why you generally don't want to commit (or
>   rollback) a transaction in a stored procedure, that makes it difficult
>   to reuse the procedure elsewhere if your transaction semantics differ.