# Using "nested" transactions in oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, transactions

I have troubles with transactions in Oracle. I have some procedures like this:

```
create or replace procedure myschema.DataSave(v_value IN NUMBER)
as
begin

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;

begin
insert/update/delete...
exception when OTHERS then goto error;
end;

COMMIT;
return;

<<error>>
ROLLBACK;
return;
end;
/
```

I am calling this procedures from c# project in this form:

```
...
string conn_str = "...";
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conn_str);
con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("", con); 

try
{
    cmd.Transaction = cmd.Connection.BeginTransaction();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // this condition simulates incorrect situations
        if (i == 5)
        {
            throw new Exception("Something is wrong.");
        }

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "myschema.DataSave";
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("v_value", OracleDbType.Int32, i, ParameterDirection.Input);
    }

    cmd.Transaction.Commit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    cmd.Transaction.Rollback();
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}   
...
```

So I am trying to use one "inner" or "nested" transaction on database layer and another "outer" transaction on application layer. But when the exception in application is thrown, the rollback doesnt work (the data seved previously - 1,2,3,4 - remain in the database). But why? I didnt have to face this problem using mssql and stored procedures in this form:

```
create procedure myschema.DataSave
@id as int
as
begin

    begin transaction

    insert/update/delete...
    if @@error > 0 goto error

    commit transaction
    return

    error:
    rollback transaction
    return
end
go
```

Im new to Oracle and couldnt find solution silimilar to this. Please somebody tell me what  I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support nested transactions.  If a transaction commits, it commits.  That's why you generally don't want to commit (or rollback) a transaction in a stored procedure, that makes it difficult to reuse the procedure elsewhere if your transaction semantics differ.

You can, however, declare a savepoint at the beginning of your procedure and rollback to that savepoint in the case of an error.  If you then remove the commit, then the transaction is solely controlled by the application code not by the database code

```
begin
  savepoint beginning_of_proc;

  insert/update/delete...

exception 
  when OTHERS then 
    rollback to beginning_of_proc;
    raise;
end;
```

In this case, though, my bias would be not to have a savepoint in the code, not to have a rollback, and not to catch the exception unless you're doing something useful with it.  Just do the DML, let any exceptions get thrown, and handle them in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are restricted to the program group they are raised in.

```
create or replace procedure myschema.DataSave(v_value IN NUMBER)
as

ex_dml_error EXCEPTION;
begin


begin
insert/update/delete...
exception 
    when OTHERS then ex_dml_error;
end;

COMMIT;

EXCEPTION 
   WHEN ex_dml_error THEN
     ROLLBACK;
end;
/
```