# Does the OracleTransaction.Rollback() supercedes commit in stored procedure?

Tags: c#, oracle, transactions, system.data.oracleclient

Suppose I have code with multiple stored procedures executing from c# code. Each of the stored procedures have a commit and a rollback in a case of exception. The exceptions are handled within these stored procedures and return a handled error messages.

If i have a an OracleTransaction.BeginTransaction() "running", on the same connection object when executing stored procedures would an OracleTransaction.Rollback() in c# code actually rollback on a data commmited by previously executed stored procedure.

Logic as follows:

1. Open connection
2. Begin transaction
3. Execute one stored procedure (with commit inside)
4. If all good, execute another stored procedure (with commit). If not, rollback previous stored procedure and stop altogether.
5. No errors commit transaction.
   Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be using the term "transaction" in a non-standard way (not consistent with the technical meaning in the context of working with a database). You don't "execute a stored procedure" within a "transaction"; rather, the other way around. You can only commit a transaction - and once it is committed, it can't be rolled back. The question is, if something in the second procedure may require you to undo what was done in the first procedure, why do you have COMMIT at the end of the first procedure to begin with?

Comment: Does anyone know what `OracleTransaction.BeginTransaction` does? From a quick search all I could find was that it _'begins a transaction at the database'_. However, in Oracle there is no special command to do that. I suspect it does nothing and is provided purely for compatibility with other RDBMS products.

Comment: @mathguy Unfortunately this is the data structure I have to deal with, it is partially a design issue that cannot be addressed. The second procedure used to be inside of the first one and would be committed within it. That query had to be taken out into it's own SP, but the data is interdependent enough, that if second fails first needs to be rolled-back as well. I was hoping to achieve nested transactions, as it is the only thing that came to mind. However, i did find this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506847/using-nested-transactions-in-oracle, which basically closes the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `COMMIT` ends the current transaction, and a new transaction begins with the next executable SQL statement. As a result a subsequent `ROLLBACK` can only undo changes made *since* the previous `COMMIT`, but not *before* that.